# Azure Event Hub : Request and response in Azure event hub through java code

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub

Suppose i have 3 users, if i send the request from these 3 users to azure event hub how to get their repective responses from azure event hub through java ? 
(particular response for particular request)

Comment: Could you describe clearly your needs? If you just need some tutorials & code samples, please see my post answer for resources.

Comment: @ Peter Pan - suppose i have 10 clients, out of them 5 send the request to azure event hub through http protocol & how to generate response to those specific partition id's from my java app.

Comment: You can use the REST API for sending event with publisher ID, please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt652152.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

@sumanth There are some resources which are very helpful for you now, that include tutorials & code samples.

1. Get started with Event Hubs for Java, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-java-ephjava-getstarted/.
2. A code sample for Event sender using JMS, please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-samples/tree/master/qpid-jms-eventhub-sender.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @ Peter Pan -   I wanna use HTTP protocol not AMQP.

Comment: on which basis client will get the response for his specific request from azure event hub

Comment: @sumanth Using HTTP protocol means using REST APIs for EventHub, please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt652149.aspx, but only support sending events.

Comment: If i use AMQP protocol, is there any extra charges regarding to Azure/AMQP.

Comment: @sumanth Not any extra charges for using AMQP on Azure. More details, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/event-hubs/.